# nextjs with redux and APIMiddleware. Rendering before SUCCESS_TYPE

Tags: node.js, redux, react-redux, next.js

I'm migrating an older application to next.js and I am having issues with `getServerSideProps` awaiting my API calls. I am using the older APIMiddleware popular with early redux actions. Essentially, Middleware that will dispatch a `REQUEST_TYPE` and an `SUCCESS_TYPE || ERROR_TYPE`. When waiting for the action to finish it naturally moves on after the `REQUEST_TYPE`. Leaving the API call to be made on the client side. When, I'd like it to complete on the server side.

I'm hoping when I come back tomorrow with a fresh eye I see an easy solution. But until then I was wondering if anyone had any input.

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => asnyc ({query}) => {
const { slug } = query;
await store.dispatch(makeAPICall(slug))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideProps` is server side code and you don't have access to any client side code.as a result,you cant dispatch your actions in any server side code including : `getServerSideProps` , `getStaticProps` , `getStaticPaths`.

go on and fetch your API inside `getServerSideProps` without using Redux.